# How does one change values at the column level in a data.frame in R using a formula?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a small sample of data, and I'm attempting to change the values in two columns based on the values which are already in those columns. The dput of the data.frame follows:

```
structure(list(Day = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 4L, 4L, 4L), DaysDead = c(5L, 45L, 60L, 10L, 
1L, 60L, 3L, 10L, 5L, NA, 1L, 6L, 10L, 20L, 45L, 2L), Month = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    Year = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 7L, 7L, 7L), CorrMonth = c(1, 0, -1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 
    2, 3, 3, 3, 0, -1, 1), CorrYear = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L)), .Names = c("Day", 
"DaysDead", "Month", "Year", "CorrMonth", "CorrYear"), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = "data.frame")
```

In the data.frame, I have two columns (CorrMonth and CorrYear) which need to be changed such that:

1. If the CorrMonth value is 0 or -1, the CorrYear value becomes CorrYear-1, otherwise it keeps its value.
2. If the CorrMonth value is 0, CorrMonth becomes 12, and if the CorrMonth value is -1, it becomes 11.

I have to change the CorrYear column first to get the correct values, then change CorrMonth.

I attempted number 1 using two different statements:

```
>Data$CorrYear<-ifelse(-1 >= (Data$CorrMonth) & (Data$CorrMonth) >=0, Data$CorrYear-1, Data$CorrYear)

>Data$CorrYear<-ifelse(-1 == (Data$CorrMonth) & (Data$CorrMonth) == 0, Data$CorrYear-1, Data$CorrYear)
```

Neither attempt produced the result I needed.

```
> Data$CorrYear
 [1] 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7
```

I can't figure out what's going on. I am not getting any errors or warning messages from R.

Comment: Your first condition for `Data$CorrMonth` is `<=-1` and `>= 0`. The second condition is also impossible (to be 1 and 0 at the same time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would skip the `ifelse` and just do this as a few separate lines of code:

```
Data$CorrYear <- Data$CorrYear - (Data$CorrMonth %in% c(-1, 0))
Data$CorrMonth[Data$CorrMonth == -1] <- 11
Data$CorrMonth[Data$CorrMonth == 0] <- 12
```

The result:

```
Data
#    Day DaysDead Month Year CorrMonth CorrYear
# 1   20        5     1    6         1        6
# 2   20       45     1    6        12        5
# 3   20       60     1    6        11        5
# 4    3       10     2    6         1        6
# 5    3        1     2    6         2        6
# 6    3       60     2    6        12        5
# 7    6        3     2    6         2        6
# 8    6       10     2    6         1        6
# 9    6        5     2    6         2        6
# 10   6       NA     2    6         2        6
# 11  11        1     3    6         3        6
# 12  11        6     3    6         3        6
# 13  11       10     3    6         3        6
# 14   4       20     1    7        12        6
# 15   4       45     1    7        11        6
# 16   4        2     1    7         1        7
```